# Whats wrong with my program? (C++)

Tags: c++, windows-7, codeblocks

I am having some problems with my program that reads, finds words containing a phrase from a file and write the results to a file.

Here is the whole program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <array>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void space();
void intro();
void again(string input3);

bool isRunning = true;

class ReadWriteFile 
{


    public:
    string input;
    string input2;
    string file;
    string tmp;

    int numberOfLines = 0;
    int counter = 0;

    void fileName()
    {
        cout << "  Enter the file name: ";

        cin >> input;

        file = input + ".txt";

        space();
        fileLength();
    }

    string fileLength()
    {
        ifstream fileStream (file/*.c_str()*/);

        if (fileStream)
        {
            while (fileStream >> tmp)
                numberOfLines++;
            // cout << numberOfLines;
            // space();
            fileInput();
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "  Wrong Input";
            space();
            fileName();
        }

        fileStream.close();
    }

    void fileInput()
    {
        string arr1 [numberOfLines];

        ifstream fileStream (file/*.c_str()*/);

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfLines; i++)
        {
            fileStream >> arr1 [i];
        }

        fileStream.close();
        orderInput(arr1);
    }

    void orderInput(string *arr1)
    {
        string arr2[numberOfLines];
        int a = 0;

        //string arr2 [numberOfLines];

        cout << "  Enter a search key phrase: ";

        cin >> input2;

        space();

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfLines; i++)
        {
            tmp = arr1[i];
            //cout << tmp;

            if (tmp.find(input2) != string::npos)
            {
                arr2[a] = tmp;
                cout << "  " << tmp << endl;
                a++;
            }
        }

        space();
        writeFile (arr2);
    }

    void writeFile (string *arr2)
    {
        ofstream fileStream ("output.txt");

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfLines; i++)
        {
            fileStream << arr2[i] << endl;
        }

        fileStream.close();

        cout << "  The results are located in the output text file named 'output'" << endl;
    }
};

ReadWriteFile  rwf;

int main ()
{
    string input3;

    intro();

    while (isRunning = true)
    {
        rwf.fileName();
        cout << "Do you want to run this program again? (y/n): ";
        cin >> input3;
        again(input3);
    }

    return 0;
}

void space()
{
    string enters = "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n";
    string rule = 
    "  --------------------\n       ----------";

    cout << endl << rule  << enters;
}

void intro()
{
    cout << endl << endl <<
    " ########## ###### ##    ## ##########"<< endl <<
    "     ##     ##      ##  ##      ##"<< endl <<
    "     ##     ##       ####       ##"<< endl <<
    "     ##     ######   ####       ##"<< endl <<
    "     ##     ##      ##  ##      ##"<< endl <<
    "     ##     ###### ##    ##     ##"<< endl <<
    " "<< endl <<
    "  ##### ######   ####    #####  ##### ##   ##"<< endl <<
    " ##     ##      ##  ##  ##     ##     ##   ##"<< endl <<
    "  ####  ##      ######  ##     ##     ##   ##"<< endl <<
    "     ## ###### ##    ## ##     ##     #######"<< endl <<
    "     ## ##     ##    ## ##     ##     ##   ##"<< endl <<
    " #####  ###### ##    ## ##      ##### ##   ##"<< endl <<
    " "<< endl <<
    " ##########  #####   #####  ##"<< endl <<
    "     ##     ##   ## ##   ## ##"<< endl <<
    "     ##     ##   ## ##   ## ##"<< endl <<
    "     ##     ##   ## ##   ## ##"<< endl <<
    "     ##     ##   ## ##   ## ##"<< endl <<
    "     ##      #####   #####  ######"<< endl << endl;
}

void again(string input3)
{
    if (input3 == "y" || input3 == "Y" || input3 == "yes" || input3 == "Yes" || input3 == "YES")
    {

    }
    else if (input3 == "n" || input3 == "N" || input3 == "no" || input3 == "No" || input3 == "NO")
    {
            isRunning = false;
    }
}
```

Here is the piece of code that I believe is causing my issues:

```
    void fileInput()
    {
        string arr1 [numberOfLines];

        ifstream fileStream (file/*.c_str()*/);

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfLines; i++)
        {
            fileStream >> arr1 [i];
        }

        fileStream.close();
        orderInput(arr1);
    }

    void orderInput(string *arr1)
    {
        string arr2[numberOfLines];
        int a = 0;

        //string arr2 [numberOfLines];

        cout << "  Enter a search key phrase: ";

        cin >> input2;

        space();

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfLines; i++)
        {
            tmp = arr1[i];
            //cout << tmp;

            if (tmp.find(input2) != string::npos)
            {
                arr2[a] = tmp;
                cout << "  " << tmp << endl;
                a++;
            }
        }

        space();
        writeFile (arr2);
    }

    void writeFile (string *arr2)
    {
        ofstream fileStream ("output.txt");

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfLines; i++)
        {
            fileStream << arr2[i] << endl;
        }

        fileStream.close();

        cout << "  The results are located in the output text file named 'output'" << endl;
    }
```

Edit: The program freezes at: "The results are located in the output text file named 'output'"

Comment: so what is your problem?

Comment: Please revise your title to be less vague. "What is wrong with my program?" could be used as the title of pretty much any question on this site.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Change

```
ifstream fileStream (file/*.c_str()*/);
```

to  `ifstream fileStream(file.c_str());` both on **fileLength()** and **fileInput()** functions.

Comment: It doesn't seem to change anything. It only gets to "The results are located in the output text file named 'output'

Comment: -1: According to [`std::ifstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/basic_ifstream), the constructor could accept a `std::string`, and no longer needs a conversion with `.c_str()`.

Comment: You use a variable 'numberoflines' as a value for the size of some arrays but you do not establish 'numberoflines' as a constant such as 'NUMBEROFLINES' and you do not initialize it as anything other than zero '0'...just saying...

Comment: your function 'string fileLength()' must return a value but does not...